# Trying to combine multiple Wordpress queries

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, meta-query, php

I am trying to query multiple post types and meta values in Wordpress... the query is trying to fetch `event` post types with a *featured* meta key, as well as `post` post types with the *featured image* set.

I am using the code below based on what I found on the [Wordpress forums](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/multiple-queries-compiling-into-one-loop?replies=5#post-1929074). It is essentially supposed to combine the two queries, grab the post IDs, and then prepare the post data.

```
<?php
    $post_types = get_post_types('events','');
    $featuredEvents = get_posts(array(
        'post_type' => $post_types,
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'showposts' => 5,
        'meta_key' => '_ecmb_featured_event',
        'meta_value' => 'on'
    ));
    $featuredNews = get_posts(array(
        'post_type' => $post_types,
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'showposts' => 5,
        'meta_query' => array(
            array(
                'key' => '_thumbnail_id',
                'compare' => 'EXISTS'
            )
        )
    ));
    $mergedPosts = array_merge( $featuredEvents, $featuredNews );
    $postIDs = array();
        foreach( $mergedPosts as $item ) {
        $postIDs[] = $item->ID;
    }
    $uniquePosts = array_unique($postIDs);

    $posts = get_posts(array(
        'post__in' => $uniquePosts,
        'post_type' => $post_types,
        'post_status' => 'publish',
    ));

    foreach( $posts as $post ) :
    setup_postdata($post);
?>


<?php
    $post_types = get_post_types('events','post');
    $featuredEvents = get_posts(array(
        'post_type' => $post_types,
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'showposts' => 5,
        'meta_key' => '_ecmb_featured_event',
        'meta_value' => 'on'
    ));
    $featuredNews = get_posts(array(
        'post_type' => $post_types,
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'showposts' => 5,
        'meta_query' => array(
            array(
                'key' => '_thumbnail_id',
                'compare' => 'EXISTS'
            )
        )
    ));
    $mergedPosts = array_merge( $featuredEvents, $featuredNews );
    $postIDs = array();
        foreach( $mergedPosts as $item ) {
        $postIDs[] = $item->ID;
    }
    $uniquePosts = array_unique($postIDs);
    $posts = get_posts(array(
        'post__in' => $uniquePosts,
        'post_type' => $post_types,
        'post_status' => 'publish',
    ));
    foreach( $posts as $post ) :
    setup_postdata($post);
?>

<?php if( get_post_type() == 'events' ) { ?>
    this is featured event
<?php } elseif (get_post_type() == 'post') { ?>
    this is a featured post
<?php } endforeach; wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

The problem is this returns 1) only the `post` post types, and 2) it throws the following error for each of the `post` post type:

`Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /MYDIR/wp-includes/functions.php on line 2688`

Would someone be kind enough to point me in the right direction?

Comment: have you looked at the correct usage of [`get_post_types`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_types) in Codex?

Comment: Actually it's a XY problem. [Others](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=combine+multiple+queries) had the same problem.

Comment: @Milo thanks, I had a look and changed it back to `get_post_types('','names')`, as well for each query I changed `'post_type' => $post_types` to `'post_type' => 'events'` and `'post_type' => 'post'`... Now however my meta query for the `post` post type isn't properly checking if the Featured Image exists. It displays any post post. Any suggestions for my featured image query?